# Need Null Results from 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 1 table `Test`

```
Cat          Art      Prc    
1           1000      100
2           1000      200
1           1500      150
2           1500      100
1           2000      250
2           2500      250
```

How do I get a result like this:

```
Art     Cat(1)    Cat(2)
1000     100       200
1500     150       100
2000     250       NULL  
2500     NULL      250


Select Art, ......
From Test
```

Comment: you have to use a PIVOT function. If there is more than 2 Cat, you will need a dynamic PIVOT. Ex : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use either LEFT JOINs or subSELECTs.

This should solve your needs by using LEFT JOINs

```
SELECT
  t.Art,
  tc1.Prc AS Cat1,
  tc2.Prc AS Cat2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Art FROM Test) t
LEFT JOIN Test tc1 ON tc1.Art=t.Art AND Cat=1
LEFT JOIN Test tc2 ON tc2.Art=t.Art AND Cat=2
```

An issue that you should be aware of... this query works as expected **IF** you have a unique or primary key on Test(Art,Cat). You didn't say anything about this in your question, but I assumed it is so.

If you have more than one row per Art - Cat combination, the query will generate strange results. You would have to aggregate Prc in some way, with a sum or an average.

But if the Cat column can contain variable values, then you should look into CROSSTAB / PIVOT queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Test Table (Cat Int, Art Int , Prc Int)

Insert @Test (Cat, Art, Prc) Values 
(1, 1000, 100),
(2, 1000, 200),
(1, 1500, 150),
(2, 1500, 100),
(1, 2000, 250),
(2, 2500, 250)

;With CTE1 As (
Select Art, Prc FRom @Test Where Cat = 1 ), CTE2 As (
Select Art, Prc FRom @Test Where Cat = 2), CTE3 As (
Select Distinct Art From @Test)
Select CTE3.Art, CTE1.Prc Cat1, CTE2.Prc Cat2
 From CTE3 
Left Join CTE1 On CTE1.Art = CTE3.Art
Left Join CTE2 On CTE2.Art = CTE3.Art
```